# Undefined method `end_with?' for "no such file to load -- Win32API":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, require, ubuntu-8.04

I'm just setting up a new server and want to install the Twitter gem but am running into problems on Ubuntu 8.04/Ruby 1.8.6

It says that "multi_json requires RubyGems >= 1.3.6", but running "gem update --system" obviously tries and updates to RubyGems 1.5 which can't be done on Ruby 1.8.6 and fails with the following error:

```
 undefined method `end_with?' for "no such file to load -- Win32API":String (NoMethodError)

 from ./lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:55
 from ./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in 'gem_original_require'
 from ./lib/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in 'require'

 ...
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: You need to provide more context for your question. As it stands right now, the answer is trivial: your problem is using a new version of the Twitter library with an old version of the Ruby platform. Ergo, either use a newer version of the Ruby platform or an older version of the Twitter library. Boom, problem solved. Easy as pie. However, presumably, there is a reason *why* you are using those versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for the lack of context - the server image I was stuck with came with Ruby 1.8.6 and didn't play nicely with RVM, and the older versions of the Twitter gem don't support OAuth that well/newer API features. Although I did manage to get RVM working and uprate it to Ruby 1.8.7 (1.9.2 handles encoding differently), which solved the issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The upgrade documentation mentions that you can use the following command to downgrade the gems. Suffice to say that it probably works for upgrading to a specific version as well:

`gem update --system 1.3.7`

In the light of the comment I just received you could also try to install an older gem your self.

For example (using root / sudo):

`cd /usr/src && wget http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.3.7.tgz`

`tar -xvf rubygems-1.3.7.tgz`

`ruby setup.rb`

Comment: This feature was added literally just today in RubyGems 1.5, which doesn't support 1.8.6.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - in the end I managed to get my system working with RVM, eliminating the issue, but I'm sure others wont be able to change their Ruby version so this could be ideal.